# How can I convert a STRING to JSON column without introducing backlashes?

Tags: google-bigquery

With a BQ table defined as above containing a STRING column

```
WITH tmp as (
    SELECT '{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}' as mycol union all
    SELECT '{"4":"4","5":"5","6":"6"}' 
)
```

how can I convert this STRING column to a JSON column so that it's `Type` is JSON here
[image]

but without the backlashes that get introduced when converting with `TO_JSON`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try parse_json keyword it will work.

```
WITH tmp as (
    SELECT '{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}' as mycol union all
    SELECT '{"4":"4","5":"5","6":"6"}' 
)
  select mycol,safe.PARSE_JSON(mycol) as mycol_json from tmp
```